# Strange behavior of graph stream

Tags: java, graph, graphstream

I am developing an application using the GraphStream library.

1. When using the standard viewer of the library every thing is normal (click inside a node to manipulate it).
2. When i am embedding it in my application, it act very strange.  to manipulate its node, I have to click outside the node to get control of it.

I think this has to do with the mouse events.

How to solve this?

**EDit**

I have solved this partially by the following change:
I had a JSplitPane containing a JPanel. this later containing the view from GraphStream library.
i removed the JPanel and i put the view from GraphStream library directly into the JSplitPane.

but i still dont know why the first solution did not work

Comment: Then you should post your code which handles your mouse events.

Comment: I have no code that handle the mouse  events. i used the standard  mouse event that came with the libaray